# How does a set iterator track elements that have been iterated in a set?

Tags: java, iterator, set

Lately, this question has been bugging me for a while. I wanted to know how a set iterator knows what it has already iterated in the set (let's say HashSets) if there is no notion of ordering in sets. Alternatively, even though the iterator iterates the set in random order, how does it know to not iterate the same element multiple times?

I know in some programming languages like C++ there are both ordered as well as unordered sets, but I am trying to see this scenario in the context of java where sets are not ordered.

Comment: It's undefined (an implementation detail). Different sets operate differently.

Comment: Java is open source. Whichever set implementation you're wondering about, go and look at the source.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I was thinking in the context of HashSets.

Comment: *High level:* `Set` implementations internally store the data in **data structures**. An `Iterator` traverses those data structures.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I tried thinking of different techniques on how it might work but couldn't get an approach. What can be a typical way to implement such functionality if there can be multiple implementations? P.S. I also tried looking at the source but it was cryptic for me to understand.

Comment: For a set to be useful and to be able to be programmed, the particular Set class (in your case, the HashSet) must be able to keep track of its internal state (which items are members). The Set uses this internal state to create an Iterator.